# unowned reference

Tags: ios, swift

using `unowned` to reference to an object:

when the object is deallocated, the other object that has a reference was marked `unowned`, that object is also deallocated at the same time. But what about that object also contains other reference to other object without marking `unowned`?

```
class Base {
    let str: String
    init(str: String){
        self.str = str
    }
    deinit {
        print("leaving Base class with string, \(str).")
    }
}
class Country {
    let name: String
    var capitalCity: City!
    init(name: String, capitalName: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.capitalCity = City(name: capitalName, country: self)
    }
    deinit {
        print("Leaving Country class")
    }
}
class City {
    let name: String
    let baseClass: Base = Base(str: "ABC") // reference to other object.
    unowned let country: Country
    init(name: String, country: Country) {
        self.name = name
        self.country = country
    }
    deinit {
        print("Leaving City class")
    }
}
var hk: Country? = Country(name: "Hong Kong", capitalName: "Central")
let central = City(name: "Central", country: hk!)
let base = central.baseClass
print("here")
hk = nil
print("here")
print(base.str)
print("here")

//print:
//here
//Leaving Country class
//Leaving City class
//leaving Base class with string, ABC.
//here
//ABC
//here
```

this object with two properties that points to two different objects. one property was marked `unowned`. the other property was not marked `unowned`. So, I thought it would have made a strong reference due to not mark `unowned` for one of the properties. but this object was still deallocated from my test code. the strange thing is after deallocation, i can still access the property. why? and how `unowned` works? how should i mark it?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Country {
    ...
    init(name: String, capitalName: String) {
        ...
        self.capitalCity = City(name: capitalName, country: self) // <-- o_O
```

The `"leaving Base class"` you see is not related to `central`.

In your `Contry`'s constructor you have created a new instance of `City`, and thus a new `Base` will also be created. So what is destroyed is just `hk!.capitalCity.baseClass` which is unrelated to `central.baseClass`.

These have nothing to do with `unowned`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at these lines of code:

```
var hk: Country? = Country(name: "Hong Kong", capitalName: "Central")
let central = City(name: "Central", country: hk!)
let base = central.baseClass
print("here")
hk = nil
print("here")
print(base.str)
print("here")
```

After the first line, three objects are created: `Country`, `City` and `Base`. Here are the references:

```
1. Country -> City: strong
2. City -> Country: weak
3. City -> Base: strong
```

After the second line, another two objects are created: another `City` and another `Base`. References:

```
4. second City -> Country: weak
5. second City -> second Base: strong
```

All right, now we deallocate `hk`! Which references will point to nothing? It's 2 and 4. This means that we can ignore them. Which reference will be destroyed? It's reference 1!

Now reference 1 is destroyed, there are no strong reference pointing to the first City you created! Hence, the first city will be deallocated and print the message.

After the first city is deallocated, there are no strong reference pointing to the first `Base` you created, and hence it is deallocated as well, printing the message.

What you are accessing in the second to last line of code, is the second City!

Here's a picture:

[image]

Dotted lines represent weak references. Non-dotted lines represent strong references.

"The second city also has no strong reference attached! Why isn't it deallocated?" you asked. Well, that is because it is stored in a local variable called `central`!

PS Hong Kong is not a country. And Central is not its capital. Central is just a busy district in Hong Kong.

Comment: Unowned reference is not the same as weak reference. When the source of a weak reference is deallocated, the target will be reassigned to nil, but for unowned the target will become a dangling pointer.

Comment: @kennytm but it behaves quite the same as weak. The only difference is that unowned can result in errors, kinda like implicitly unwrapped optionals.